# Outlook add-in not able to write to registry location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin

I am using Outlook Click To Run version and have my C++ add-in registered with it.

When writing Key to registry location **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE** it is wrongly writing to the location ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software.***

Why API redirecting my write operation to wrong location??? I can read correctly from **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE** location but write redirects it to above mentioned location.

I do have admin rights to write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. I am opening Outlook with administrator user.

Below is my sample code:

```
            string wstrAddinKey("SOFTWARE\\XYZ");
            LONG lStatus = RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, wstrAddinKey.c_str(), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL,  &hKey1, &dwDisposition);
            if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
            CHAR pwszStrBuf[2] = { "1" };
            pwszStrBuf[2] = '\0';
            DWORD keyLen = (DWORD)strlen(pwszStrBuf);
                    lStatus = RegSetValueExA(hKey1, "TestKey", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&pwszStrBuf, (sizeof(CHAR) * keyLen) + 1);
                    if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
}
}
```

Comment: The `Computer/` prefix is always present. So, you *are* writing to the `HKLM\Software` key, as far as I can tell.

Comment: ... but maybe  misunderstood. Why the double-double backslashes in `SOFTWARE\\\\XYZ`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am writing to HKLM\Software\XYZ location. why it is writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\XYZ location?? (removed the extra \\)

Comment: Removed the extra \\ and Computer/ added by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are running inside Outlook, which might redirect registry calls. You can disable that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector

On a separate note, writing to HKLM from a non-elevated app is a recipe for a disaster.